# Tell ts that one of two variables will exist

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
const var1: Record<string, unknown> | undefined = undefined;
const var2: string | undefined = "Hi";

if(!var1 && !var2) /* THROW ERROR */

const obj: string | Record<string, unknown> = var1 | var2 /* TS ERROR */
```

After if statement typescript knows that at least one of the variables exist, but it cannot know for sure which one exist so it makes sense that it's throwing the following error.

TS ERROR :

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Record<string, unknown>'.

Im trying to avoid additional if statement in variable assignment.

It's there something that im missing in this logic?

Comment: If there is a relationship between these two variables, you can package them together into a single object and let the object's type be a union type like `{var1: Record<string, unknown>, var2?: string} | {var1?: Record<string, unknown>, var2: string}`. Alternatively you can use a discriminated union like `{kind: 'record', value: Record<string, unknown>} | {kind: 'string', value: string}` if exactly one should be present (not both).

Comment: Im not following you, jaja sorry. Could u explain me again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has a rough time trying to keep track of the types of multiple variables and how each depends on the other. The exact solution that's right for you will likely depend on exactly how you are using those two varaibles.

But given what you've posted, I would probably combine them into one value, and then test that one value.

For example:

```
const var1: Record<string, unknown> | undefined = undefined;
const var2: string | undefined = "Hi";

function foo() {
    const obj: string | Record<string, unknown> | undefined = var1 || var2
    if(!obj) throw new Error("foo")
    // obj exists here
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EYBcMBKBTUSAmAPNEgJZgDmANDAK5gDWYIA7mAHwwA+dY+2AM3LZ8MALy9+QsCIDcAKFCRYiJACYMJchW6TBw0RIBEACVJGF8gfWBRS4GAJAgAFAEoYAb3kxfMJdAwIABGAFaaUGSUujh4RFqUNPRMrBy69FIG4vDIKNw8qmo+fqQCLgCEIaEeUAAWSKwwMiwwAKJIDUguRk4gRm7FvgD0Q0FhMNgAHqTQEDC12EjY8gC+8kA)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @kaya3, that was embarrassing :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But for my use case, it won't work. Variable `obj` its strictly of type `string | Record<string, unknown>`. I could use ternary operator on assignment but it's the thing im trying to avoid.

Comment: After some code refactor, this is PERFECT! for my use case. Thanks a lot!